# ifndef with cpp file in new library

Tags: c++, c++11, inner-classes

Hello im trying to build my own library in c++, and after many hours of searching and trying i learnt that a good way of doing one would be using nested classes, so i made some code in this form of tree:
[file tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lIux.png)

So i divided all the class files into different header files(i know this is harder and maybe not necessary but i wanted have it like that, if nothing more then just for training). And so to keep the nested class connected, but in different files, each header needs to include its child and or parent to function correctly. This didnt work, gave me errors of recursive include (duh) so i searched online and found #ifndef and #define and i used them in this way:

```cpp
    //A.hpp
    #ifndef A_HPP_INCLUDED   // some unique macro
    #define A_HPP_INCLUDED

    class A
    {
    public:
        class B;
        class C;
        
    };
    #include "B.hpp"
    #include "C.hpp"
    #endif

    //B.hpp
    #ifndef B_HPP_INCLUDED
    #define B_HPP_INCLUDED

    #include "A.hpp"
    class A::B
    {
    public:
        static int num;
        void func();
    };
    #endif
    int A::B num = 5;

    //C.hpp
    #ifndef C_HPP_INCLUDED   // some unique macro
    #define C_HPP_INCLUDED

    #include "A.hpp"
    class A::C
    {
    public:
        void func();
    };
    #endif
```

But the second i add #include "B.hpp" into the B.cpp file it immediately gives me error that all variables and functions ive added in this way are defined multiple times. Without cpp files it works perfectly, but with them it crashes. In fact this happens when adding any cpp file to any header

Answers to this problem are welcome, but if you have any tips on how to make library files in a better way or even just random tips, thatd be awesome!

fyi im using qt creator, qmake, c++11. if qmake file is needed ill send it but i think everything there is good.

The files in question (for reproducing the problem):

```cpp
    //testlibrary.hpp

    #ifndef TESTLIBRARY_HPP_INCLUDED   // some unique macro
    #define TESTLIBRARY_HPP_INCLUDED

    class TestLibrary
    {
    public:
        class Core;
        class SFML;
    };
    #include <Core/Core.hpp>
    #include <SFML++/SFMLpp.hpp>
    #endif


    //Core.hpp
    #pragma once

    #ifndef CORE_HPP_INCLUDED   // some unique macro
    #define CORE_HPP_INCLUDED

    #include <testlibrary.hpp>

    class TestLibrary::Core
    {
    public:
        class Constants;
    };
    #include "Constants.hpp"
    #endif


    //Constants.hpp
    #pragma once
    #ifndef CONSTANTS_HPP_INCLUDED   // some unique macro
    #define CONSTANTS_HPP_INCLUDED
    #include "Core.hpp"
    class TestLibrary::Core::Constants
    {
    public:
        static float const_PI;
        static float const_Euler;
        Constants();
    };
    float TestLibrary::Core::Constants::const_PI = 3.1415;
    float TestLibrary::Core::Constants::const_Euler = 2.71828;
    #endif


    //SFMLpp.hpp
    #pragma once
    #include <SFML/Window.hpp>
    #include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
    #ifndef SFML_HPP_INCLUDED   // some unique macro
    #define SFML_HPP_INCLUDED
    #include <testlibrary.hpp>
    class TestLibrary::SFML
    {
    public:
        class Text;
    };

    //#include "Text.hpp"
    #endif


    //Text.hpp
    #pragma once

    #ifndef TEXT_HPP_INCLUDED   // some unique macro
    #define TEXT_HPP_INCLUDED
    #include "SFMLpp.hpp"
    class TestLibrary::SFML::Text : public sf::Text
    {
    public:
        sf::Font font_;

        Text();
        Text(std::string string);
        Text(std::string string, sf::Font &font);
        Text(std::string string, sf::Font &font, int size);
        Text(std::string string, sf::Font &font, int size, sf::Color color);

        void setTextInt(int inputText);
        void drawText(sf::RenderWindow &window);
    };

    #endif


    //text.cpp
    #include "text.hpp"
```

[image: The error messages]

Comment: This question's shown code fails to meet Stackoverflow's requirements for showing a [mre]. Because of that it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You need to [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste ***exactly as shown***, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part, this includes any ancillary information, like any input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: `A::B num` is defined outside of the header guard... Furthermore including the header in multiple sources will result in linker errors.

Comment: I've added my actual problematic code. thanks for telling me. Regarding A::B::num being outside of header guard, it doesnt work even if its inside it. furthermore im not including headers in multiple sources. or at least its not what i think i did. Thank you in advance

Comment: You do have a single .cpp file? Did you read the preprocessed version of it? Try `-E` compiler switch.

Comment: You should not use the javascript code formatting. See the console.log example here for code formatting: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) To add c++ use ```c++ as the starting tag on its own line

Comment: Yes i only have one cpp file as i only started making them for the library. also i dont know how/where to do the compiler switch unfortunately this is my first time playing around with more than just #include xyz.hpp

Comment: That looks like a Java or C# construct, which C++ would use namespaces for. Classes without member variables is a "code smell".

Comment: code small hm? XD i've never had java or c# im purley basing my code off knowledge from uni as well as self taught on trial and errors. Would namespaces be better for such a library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables must be defined only once in the entire program. If you define them in a header file, they are defined in every .cpp file that includes the header.

Move these lines into a .cpp file:

```
float TestLibrary::Core::Constants::const_PI = 3.1415;
float TestLibrary::Core::Constants::const_Euler = 2.71828;
```

Or use `constexpr` to define them in place:

```
class TestLibrary::Core::Constants
{
public:
    static constexpr float const_PI = 3.1415;
    static constexpr float const_Euler = 2.71828;
```

Answer (score 1):

In header files you should have only declarations (except templates but it is not a case here), statements like:

```
float TestLibrary::Core::Constants::const_PI = 3.1415;
float TestLibrary::Core::Constants::const_Euler = 2.71828;
```

are definitions and that is why you have error. These statements should be in some c++ file.